# How can I delete xml file with Xml writer?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, visual-studio

I can't find any resource on how to delete an xml file with xml writer or at least clear its contents, is it possible or something else needs to be use?

I need to preform simple clear or delete on an xml file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to delete the file, just do this:

```
File.Delete(path);
```

If you want to clear its contents:

```
File.WriteAllText(path, "");
```

If you're doing a lot of I/O, get familiar with the static [`File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) methods.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need anything xml specific. You can use `File.Delete("path to file")`

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand you have a variable of `XmlWriter` and you need to delete the file pointed by it.

If so, answer is you can't do that **reliably**. Note that `XmlWriter` not necessarily points to a file. What will you do in the following case?

```
var writer = new XmlTextWriter(new MemoryStream(),Encoding.Default);
```

No file is involved here and nothing to delete. If you have the path of the file [here's how you go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23640546/2530848)